# ternary condition not working inside innerHTML in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code

```
{{ Name && Name.length > 20 ? (Name | slice: 0:20) + "..." : Name }}
```

this is working inside div but when i try to use it inside innerHTML its giving syntax error

```
<div [innerHTML]='Name && Name.length > 20) ? "(Name| slice: 0:20 + "..."" : "Name"'>

</div>
```

pls provide solution to fix.

Comment: Create a string field for your Evaluation inside the component.ts file and bind that field to the innerHtml. And use double quotes in the Html Template :)

Comment: @Loop Can you pls show with any example

Answer (score 0):

you have used
[innerHTML]='Name && Name.length > 20) ? "(Name| slice: 0:20 + "..."" : "Name"'

here backet open close in wrong places, also you have slice the name with double quote.

So please check the below code.

```html
<div [innerHTML]='Name && Name.length > 20 ? (Name | slice: 0:20) + "..."  : Name'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of mismatch from your code and your html. Carried away by the quotes, I guess ;-)

```
<div [innerHTML]='Name && Name.length > 20 ? (Name | slice: 0:20) + "..." : Name'>

</div>
```

Reduces

```
Name ="KJLFHSLKJDFLJKSDHFJKLSKJLDFHJKLSHJDKLHFSK"
```

To

```
KJLFHSLKJDFLJKSDHFJK...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the brackets properly, this should be the right code

```
<div [innerHTML]="Name && Name.length > 20 ? '(Name| slice: 0:20) + "..."" : 'Name' ">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that apart from what was already suggested, there are also a missing parenthesis. The code should look like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]=" Name && (Name.length > 20 ? (Name.slice(0,20) + '...') : Name) "></div>
```